# to copy a file using dbms_file_transfer.copy_file procedure file size must be in the multiples of 512bytes?

Tags: oracle11g

Can any body explain why the DBMS_file_transfer .copy procedure will take a file and its size must be in multiples of 512 bytes? this procedure is used to copy files from one location to another location in the same server but this files shows an error when the file size(source file) in around 493 MB(517403648 bytes).

Thanks in advace

Comment: Any particular error? Are you asking whether that restriction exists (as stated in the docs), or why it does?

Comment: @AlexPoole i am asking any restrictions and reasons for that procedure